# Demandware Business Manager: Is it possible to show ATS in the Catalog List View?

Tags: demandware

In the Business Manger, under **Merchant Tools ➤ Products and Catalogs ➤ Catalogs**, the Grid View currently shows Available-to-Sell (ATS) information:

[image: grid view shows ATS]

However, the **List View** does not show that information:

[image: list view does NOT show ATS]

Is it possible to configure the Business Manager to show a column for ATS in List View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to configure BM to show a column for ATS, as it is not product attribute. However you can add additional product attributes in `Product Preferences`under `Global Preferences`.